# Hide parameters in the url, using Java Play Framework

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to hide url parameters in Java Play Framework 2.x? I found a simular question but he wanted to hide them to stop url hacking. So he got other answers/solutions than hide the url.

The thing is that I have some "info objects", that has an ID that I need to pass to several actions, jquery and so on, so I need to have it in the url. But I don't want any user to see the ID's.

For example I have this conf:

```
GET     /deliverablegraph           controllers.Application.deliverable_graph(id:Long,contextId:Long)
```

That is showed like ../deliverablegraph?id=xxxx&contextId=yyyy

I only want to show ../deliverablegraph, but need access to the id and contextId.

Comment: Hiding URL parameters is almost certainly the wrong thing to do. Why do you (think you) need to do this?

Comment: The ID's should be secret to the user, BUT I need the ID's to be sent between different pages (could use another solution I think) AND for jquery. Like, when you click on something, do this ("this" is using the id).

Comment: You can render them as part of the page in a hidden form field or as a javascript variable, but there is no "hiding" them from the user. If you need those values for javascript then a person that wants to is going to be able to access them too. What you can do is generate some sort of hash from your ids and pass it along with the ids. That way you have some way of checking if the id values have been messed with.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem about hiding parameters in the URL and I hope my solution helps you in a way. The only difference is that I didn't want to pass through extremely long URL parameters because I needed to pass through JSON data. Unlike your issue where you don't want to pass through secret information.

So I did what estmatic said in his comment about placing the information in a hidden form field:

```
<form class='someDynamicForm' method='post' action='@routes.Application.function()'>
    <textarea name="jsonHolder" style="display: none">
        "Used javascript to insert the data I want in here"
    </textarea>
</form>
```

For more flexibility you don't have to use a `button` to submit. Whenever you're ready to submit the form you can always call the javascript code `document.someDynamicForm.submit();`

Now at the controller end, you can retrieve the information in the textarea by doing:

```
public static Result function() {
    DynamicForm dynamicForm = DynamicForm.form().bindFromRequest();
    String jsonData = dynamicForm.get("jsonHolder");
    return;
}
```

And then in your routes file make sure to speficy:

```
POST       /json           controllers.Application.function()
```

The downside here is that you want your IDs to be a secret. All the "hacker" has to do then is do a right-click -> view page source and they can see the information in the hidden textfield.

Another solution that I have done to pass along information throughout the web session is use Play's built in `Session` http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaSessionFlash

Have you looked into using something like that? Since it seems like you'll be using the user's ID a lot, saving their ID information in the Session (which ultimately is exposed in their cookies) might be something to look into.

Comment: Thank you! I think something of this is the way to do it, even if it's not really secured (at all :)). I didn't thought in the beginning it was possible, but I took a chance and asked here.

Comment: If the ID's are really that sensitive, then I think you should looking into hashing the ID's and then have the controller do the verification.